# remove query string

Tags: cakephp, get, query-string

I'm using an ancient API, that sends the result over `GET` method to my app. So user will redirect to my action with a url like that:

```
http://example.com/api/result?request=102&state=1
```

It's doesn't look like nice.. also I don't want the user knows his `request` and `state` (which the API sends by `GET` and I can't set it to post them)

Can `CakePHP` get the query string and store it in session then removes it from url? automatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it cant. Since you are using an ancient API and **cannot** change the request method to POST, theres nothing any framework could do.

But you could do something like change the URL pretty fast (depends on the user connection/browser speed) using something like the PHP function `header("LOCATION: http://example.com/api/result");`
Still, the user could see for a brief moment the request and state values. Or he can always stop the request pressing the browser stop button...

Comment: Ok, So I wrote an extra action to store query string in session and redirect user to new page without the query strings.